# Is there a simple way to force targets to be up to date?

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I was wondering if there is a way to force targets to be up to date using drake. 
I wrote some new functions and now suddely all my targets are outdated. I have no idea why this happened. Now, I am very sure that I didn't change the previous functions. Worst case, I added a comment or space. The analysis I am running takes days and I want to avoid having to rerun the whole plan. 
Is it possible to tell drake that my targets are fine and not outdated?

Thanks!

Comment: You can change the trigger conditions in `make`, but this is probably a bad idea. My experience with finding that all targets are unexpectedly out of date is that I have somehow not loaded the functions I need. Now I use `drake::r_make` which stops me making silly mistakes.

Comment: Well said, Richard. Nina, another FYI: if you change comments and whitespace in your functions or plan, `drake` does not rebuild targets. If you want to test this, you can run `make(drake_plan(x = 1 + 1))` and then `make(drake_plan(x = 1+1))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will check out `r_make()`!